# Copy/Paste with link

Tags: excel, vba

I need to copy/paste a range with link.

I know it is with the Link:=True, but I Don't know how to modify my code to put it in.

```
Sheets("Remboursement").Select 'select the sheet to copy
Dim maplage As Range ' set range
Set maplage = Range("B2:E140").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) 
maplage.Copy 'copy only visible cells
With Sheets("Controle")
        .Activate ' activate the destination sheet
        .Range("T3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _ 'paste the values
                              SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
End With
Set maplage = Nothing
```

I tried with :

```
.Range("T3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
                              SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

But as usual, it doesn't work. It is a part of a long code that I made in 1 month, so I am little bit afraid to change it, that's why I ask to you first.

Comment: Try to remove `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) ` and change `SkipBlanks:=False` to `SkipBlanks:=True`

Comment: I need to copy only the visible cells, it's why the maccro is created for. I changed skipBlanks but it changes nothing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Range.PasteSpecial`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.pastespecial) does not have a `Link` parameter.

You are looking for [`Worksheet.Paste`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.paste):

This is one of the few cases where you *do* need to `Select`, per the documentation...

> If this argument (`Link`) is specified, the `Destination` argument cannot be used....
>   If you don't specify the `Destination` argument, you must select the destination range before you use this method.

```
With Sheets("Controle")
     .Activate
     .Range("T3").Select
     .Paste Link:=True
```

Comment: Thank you, there is the link. But now it changes the Format...

Comment: The range have severals format : Date in first column, Standard column 2 & 3, % (with 2 number after comma) in column 4.

Comment: Hmm... you could always reapply the formatting after pasting.. not sure if there's a better way than that.

Comment: Can I paste with the link and only the values ? with Something like Paste:=xlPasteValues ?

Comment: You have to use a workaround it seems. That's what my previous comment alluded to.